# Oblique motion in more than 2 parts

Tags: analysis

I've always been taught to ask questions even if I'm quite sure about being correct. It never hurts to ask, as I'm always learning!

I've seen and heard contrapuntal pieces, mostly in the works of Bach, and in my experience I'm pretty sure I've seen instances in Bach's music where he has more than two voices or even 3 moving in oblique motion while a fourth part ascends or descends. However, I've read the usual definition of oblique motion which states oblique motion occurs when one voice stays the same and the other part moves up or down by step or leap. The meaning of this definition applies for two part harmony.

My question is simple; isn't it completely fine for oblique motion to occur in more than 2 voices? For example, playing an F# Major triad where the chord tones F# A# and C# all stay the same while a 4th part, a nonchord tone, an F, ascends or descends in oblique motion?

I'm trying my best to make sense. Thankyou to anyone who can share their knowledge and expertise! I greatly appreciate it!

Answer (score 1):

The primary concern in contrapuntal polyphony is the independence of the voices. If two or more voices simultaneously sustain their respective pitches, there's a danger of losing their independence from each other. A composition could contain such moments, but the composer would have to employ them carefully in order to maintain the contrapuntal aesthetic.